# log INFO from shell script are not displaying when we trigger shell script from python program

Tags: python, shell, process, subprocess

I am calling shell script from my pyhton program and the shell script is having INFO & DEBUG logs as part the output.
When i run the shell script from python program, i can see only standard output, but not the INFO & DEBUG logs which are output of shell script.

**My Code:**

```
   process = subprocess.Popen(['bash','/myshell_script.sh',env, params],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

   while (True):
     retcode = process.poll()  # returns None while subprocess is running
     line = process.stdout.readline()
     **print(line)**
     if (retcode is not None):
        break
```

here when i print the shell script output, i can see only partial output and cannot see the output like '18/10/20 11:24:55 INFO test test' (Which is shell script output)

Could someone help me to provide some info how can i get all the shell script output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your script is sending `INFO` and `DEBUG` logs to `stderr`. You can try just to remove `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, to see if the output appears in terminal.

If you really need the `subprocess.PIPE` for `stderr`, say you want to capture the `stderr` output from Python, you will need to call `process.communicate()` see more info [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @beezz. You are correct, i removed stderr and can see the output in the terminal. I modified my script to read from **'stderr'** intead of **'stdout'**. Now its working fine.